# unable to update android studio to 4.0

Tags: android, windows

Whenever I try to update android studio, it downloads and then after validating a dialog box says:

```
File - plugins/copyright/lib/copyright.jar      
Action - Update    
Problem - Modified     
Solution - none
```

Screenshot:
[image]

I want to use new Motion Layout.

Comment: I faced the same error for another plugin, so re-installed Android Studio 4.0 from the installer.

Comment: do I have to Uninstall previous version of Android Studio then?

Comment: I think so. Because your `copyright.jar` is modified, updater can't do incremental update. To uninstall and re-install it you will surely get proper version plugins.

Comment: But why is my copyright.jar is modified? I tried updating many times even by disabling both avast and windows firewall and core shield coz i thought they are the one modifying the update files.